# React useEffect detect changes in an array inside the object

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to recall an API based on a state change, using useEffect hook. However, my useEffect can't detect changes made to the 'type' array. I tried using use-deep-compare-effect library, but it also couldn't detect a change.

How I can detect changes to my state?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
        query: '',
        type: ["Tender & Auction", "Merger & Acquisition","Policy & Regulation", "Project Update", "Other"]
    })

 /// Re-run a query, after we check a filter
    useEffect(() => {
          searchAPI(values);
      }, [values]);
```

I am changing the values like this:

```
 const handleChange = (newValues) => {
        console.log(newValues)
        setValues({ ...values, type: newValues})
   };
```

Comment: Add your code, where you are changing the values

Comment: Thanks @sojin, added the changes logic, I can see that state changed in my console.

Comment: `setValues({ ...values, type: [...newValues]})`. do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple way of doing comparison without causing an infinite loop:

```
useEffect(() => {
    searchAPI(values);
}, [JSON.stringify(values)]);
```

or if you only need to track type property:

```
useEffect(() => {
    searchAPI(values);
}, [JSON.stringify(values.type)]);
```

Comment: Thank you @SoGoddamnUgly, I've used JSON.stringify(values.type) and it worked!

Comment: Please, never go with this way. It’s an anti pattern.

Comment: @LongNguyen what should I use instead?

Comment: Did you try with sojin solution? Can you add the way you call handle change to get more help?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the scope

```
useEffect(() => {
    searchAPI(values);
}, [values,values.type]);
```